# Few Problems About Trail Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, detection, renderer

I have few problems with trail renderer. I have a cube which has trail renderer and boarders at the edges of the gameplay screen.

What I want to do is that when my cube leaves any of the boarder I want to activate trail renderer , when go back to boarder deactivate it and destroy the closed curve bounded by my cube(trail).

Below is my attempt:

```
void OnTriggerStay()
{
    trailrend.enabled = false;
    trailrend.time = 0f;
}
void OnTriggerExit()                           //trailrend gets component
{
    trailrend.enabled = true;
    trailrend.time = 1000f;
}
```

But as you might observe when I exit the trigger and activate the trail I see the past-trails again which I do not want to.

My second question is how to detect the area bounded by the trail.

I could not try much for this but I tried to get the vertex positions to figure out / estimate  the area bounded by trail and boarders but I failed using trailrend.GetPositions.

I would like some help. Maybe there are better ways to do these I don't know.

Thank you

**EDIT**: I want trail to stay as much as possible when cube in the field. That's why I set it to 1000sec.

Answer (score 0):

Add a child dummy object to your main object. The dummy object can be a prefab with the trail renderer on it.

Destroy the dummy object `OnTriggerStay()`

Re add new one `OnTriggerExit()`